# HTML element width changes when Restore Down button is clicked

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML table in a page and I set the width of a column of the table to a fixed width by setting `<td style="width: 300px">` to all `<td>` elements in that column. However when I press Restore Down button of the browser, the width of the column gets smaller and causes my tags to get cramped. What is happening here?

Comment: Where is the Restore Down button in a browser?

Comment: I think he means the un-maximize button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what I figured, upon clicking the Restore Down button, the browsers automatically readjust the width of HTML table columns,thereby overriding your fixed length. The best way to deal with it would be to set a min-width for the div block that contains the tags.